# Can you point me to a large Python open-source project?

Tags: python, open-source

I would like to see how a large (>40 developers) project done with Python looks like:

- how the code looks like
- what folder structure they use
- what tools they use
- how they set up the collaboration environment
- what kind of documentation they provide

It doesn't matter what type of software it is (server, client, application, web, ...) but I would prefer something mature (version 1.0 already done)

Comment: should be community wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Chandler](http://chandlerproject.org/) is a really huge one that had problems because of its size and the developers working on it, so you can learn from their failures. There's a [book](http://www.dreamingincode.com/) written about it too.

[Wingware Python IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) is a huge project, unfortunately it's closed source. But I think it's still interesting to see what a large desktop application is like in Python.

Answer (score 11):

The [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework.

Also, [Twisted Matrix](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

I am not sure about the exact number of developers, though.

Comment: Look at http://www.djangoproject.com/community/ -- there are a lot of folks making contributions.  Some are quite small.  Some are large.

Answer (score 9):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) - which coincidentally is also usable for the collaboration environment part of your question.

Answer (score 6):

- [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) - Issue Tracker
- [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) - Network Programming Framework
- [Zenoss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zenoss/) - Network Monitor
- [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/) - SCM Tool

Answer (score 6):

There are about 40 developers working on [the language itself](http://www.python.org/dev/why/).  You can take a [look at the repository](http://www.python.org/dev/faq/#how-do-i-get-a-checkout-of-the-repository-read-only-and-read-write) or [download the source [ftp]](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/Python-2.6.2.tgz) to see style, organization, &c.

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LargePythonProjects) are some other large Python projects (lines-of-code large).

Comment: This reminds me of PyPy, too.

Answer (score 3):

The [Plone](http://plone.org/) CMS and the [Zope](http://www.zope.org/) application server on which Plone runs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps more low-level than you're looking for but the [NumPy](http://numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://scipy.org) projects are very mature, open source, numerical and scientific programming libraries. Although the API is Python, much of the low-level work is done in C or Fortran.

The [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) project is a pure-python project that is also quite mature.

Answer (score 2):

Is [pinax](http://github.com/pinax/pinax/tree/master) big enough? or [ella](http://github.com/ella/ella/tree/master)?

I'm not sure of the developer count, but they are big and have a fair number of forks.

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) would probably qualify.

Answer (score 2):

[PyQt4](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt4) is a large project.

Here is a list with the [most popular python projects](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MostPopularPythonProjects).

Answer (score 1):

Pylons.

Even it is 0.9.8, it is quite mature