# Python 3 and open source: Are there any good projects?

Tags: python, open-source, python-3.x

I've been studying Python 3 recently and I have come across a conundrum: I want to expand my abilities by working on an open source project, but I seem to have trouble finding any specifically for Python 3.

I know that this question has been asked before:
[Such as here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117561/what-are-good-open-source-projects-in-python-for-which-i-can-be-a-contributor)
[And here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161339/can-you-point-me-to-a-large-python-open-source-project),
Unfortunately these all seem to be using Python <= 2.6 and I want to use >= 3.0

This leads me to another question:
Python 3.0 has been out for almost a year, yet most of the examples and 90% of the projects are for <= 2.6.  I also know that the MySQL library is not in a Python 3 compatible state.  Does this mean that I'd actually better off learning Python 2.x and assume the incompatible 3.0 will die?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to help out with Python 3, find some libraries that haven't been ported yet and help port them. Projects that depend on these libraries can't make the switch until the libraries do.

Answer (score 4):

Major point releases of languages take an exceedingly long time for wide adoption. Python 3 will not die -- eventually people will switch, but it may take many years.

Answer (score 0):

PyPI lists [a handful of packages ported to Python3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all) of which **[lxml](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/)** and **[httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/)** are some of the prominent ones.

Comment: It now shows a plethora of them are converted to Python 3. (: